# How to Compare DATE of current day with stored date in SQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, appointment

I'm working on an Appointment Form where a customer fills details for current day or for upcoming 2 days. In the form, there are 3 option of days

1. Current Day (Tuesday)
2. Tomorrow +1 (Wednesday)
3. Day Tomorrow +2 (Thursday)

as shown in the image:

[image]

Now I'm fetching time and date from database (selecting time from the database is working). What I need is to match the current day date, tomorrow day date and day tomorrow day date to match with database dates. If they are available in the database it will disable checkbox for that DAY Date Time.

PHP code I have used

```
    $date = new DateTime('+1 day');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE c_time = '01:00' AND  c_date='$date' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Can not fetch Data from Database". mysqli_error($conn));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $a = $row['c_time'];
    if(empty($a)){
        #checkbox available (in green color)
    } else {
        #checkbox not available (In red Color)
    }
```

I need to make the date of database with current date so it will show the disabled (appointed times) checkbox in reds according to date columns.

Current date function should be dynamic so it will automatically swap the current day appointed times with coming day appointments.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You may be vulnerable to SQL injection, if any data information is obtained from user input. Please _urgently_ convert to parameter binding, to keep your system and your users safe.

Comment: I wonder if you need to adjust this question to be more specific. It seems like you made a start on the problem, and would like someone to do the rest of the work. Is it not better if you do it? What are you stuck on in particular?

Comment: No i dont want anyone to do the rest for me. just want to know how it will be done as im stuck here. at putting c_date = ($current date). the current date is variable .. how i can compare a variable with the date fetching from database.. 
need to compare 2 things at the same time in query. is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all i have found the way how i can compare and get the accurate result from phpmyadmin Database on the basis of date. 
 the main thing to use is CAST()

```
cast((now() + interval 1 day) as date)
```

full Query is

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE c_time = '01:00' AND  c_date= cast((now() + interval 1 day) as date)";
```

Thanks